# Getting vector subscript out of range exception

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> arr = { -12, 14, 71, 123, 12, -14, 5, 5, -75, 12, -1, 51, 12, 61, -61, -13 };
    int n = arr.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
            else if (arr[j] == arr[j + 1])
            {
                for (int a = j + 1; a < n; a++)
                {
                    arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i : arr)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works if I use an array but it shown "vector subscript out of range" when I use vector. Could anyone please explain why is it an error there?

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases. Start with a vector of only one element. This makes it much easier to reason about what happens.

Comment: What element does `arr[j + 1]` refer to ?  Are there any differences between plain old arrays and vectors ?  (Hint, the answer is 'yes'.)

Comment: A good example of why vectors are better than arrays. Your code is bugged in both cases (see answers below) but an error only shows when you use a vector. When a bugged program shows an error that's a *good thing*.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined when you are using an array or a vector.   You're getting lucky that you are using an implementation of `std::vector` that checks for out of bounds access (which is not actually required by the standard, unless you use the vector's `.at()` member function).     In both cases, the usage of `arr[j+1]` has undefined behaviour in your code when `j == n-1`.     Bear in mind that "undefined behaviour" does not mean "an error will occur" - it is quite common for undefined behaviour to result in no observable symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following fragment of your code:

```
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
```

What will happen on the last loop iteration, when `j = n - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access out-of-bound array with this line:

```
arr[j + 1] AND arr[a + 1]
```

because it is iterating only till `n`. In the last valid iteration, the program tries to obtain the value of `j + 1`th and `n + 1`th indices respectively whereas the size of the array is `n`.

To solve this issue, you need to iterate till `n - 1` condition. Just replace those `n` contained in the nested two For loops so that it will correctly iterate till the end of the loop.

Comment: ok, now I know that where I got wrong but why does this works when I used array instead of vector?

Comment: @luke97 Your code will stay wrong in any aspect. The vector is a Class which contains lots of helpful methods and functions and ability to resist any unwanted results. On the other hand, an array has no such functionalities, it does not warns if the programmer is attempting to access out of bound array length which causes UB silently.

Answer (score 0):

your vector element size is n. But,you are using index over n incase of arr[j+1] and arr[a+1].

Just put condition checking, `i < n-1 , j < n-1 and a < n-1`

Here is the updated code:

```
vector <int> arr = { -12, 14, 71, 123, 12, -14, 5, 5, -75, 12, -1, 51, 12, 61, -61, -13 };
        int n = arr.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
            {
                if ( arr[j] < arr[j + 1] ) 
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
                else if ( arr[j] == arr[j + 1])
                {
                    for (int a = j + 1; a < n - 1; a++)
                    {
                        arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i : arr)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Made it worse. Why not just iterate till `n - 1`?

Comment: Yes. that's better. In that case no need for added checking